# How can I toggle property in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have built a cart app with this reducer in reactjs/redux:

```
const initialState = {
    items: [],
    cartOpen: false,
    total: 0
}

const Cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            let newstate = [...state, action.payload];
            var newTotal = 0;
            newstate.forEach(it => {
                newTotal += it.item.price;
            });
            newstate.total = newTotal;
            newstate.cartOpen =true
            return newstate;

        case 'TOGGLE_CART':
            debugger;
            return !state.cartOpen;

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default Cart;
```

I am trying to set the state for the cart ie open but when I check the logs the cart property is updated and not the cartOpen property?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Redux assumes that you never mutate the objects it gives to you in the
>   reducer. **Every single time, you must return the new state object**.
>   Even if you don't use a library like [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), you need to completely
>   avoid mutation.

```
case 'TOGGLE_CART':
    return !state.cartOpen;
```

Doing ^^ this is mutating your state (corrupting your state object). When you don't guarantee immutability, Redux loses its predictability and efficiency.

To achieve immutable state, we can use vanilla `Object.assign` or its more elegant alternative [object spread syntax](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).

```
case 'TOGGLE_CART':
    return {
        ...state,
        cartOpen: !state.cartOpen
    }
```

Comment: I don't really change the state I just return a Boolean value?

Comment: I accidentally pressed enter key, ok here is the rest of my previous comment:
`initialState = { a: 1, b: 2, cartOpen: false }`
now if your reducer returns `return !state.cartOpen` then console.log(state) will yield a boolean `true` (but you wanted `{ a: 1, b: 2, cartOpen: true }`). Which means you've lost all other properties `a`, `b` etc in your state object. Essentially you've mutated or corrupted your state.

Comment: Maybe a little pedantic, but OP is right: he isn't actually mutating state. He's just not giving back the complete state. Definitely two different things. I suppose one could argue that he's mutating the _shape_ of the state tree, but that isn't what the quoted docs are referring to.

Comment: how I see it is like, mutation is said to be happened if we are not returning a new state object.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but even if a new object is created, invoking the 'TOGGLE_CART' action back to back will result in different results (i.e cartOpen is either true or false). Therefore, this reducer is not idempotent and consequently, not pure, in violation of Redux's reducer purity requirement.

Answer (score 6):

Your reducer must always return the complete slice of the app's state for which it is responsible. For `TOGGLE_CART`, you are only returning the boolean value for `openCart`.

Instead, create a copy of the previous state object and only update the single property you want to change:

```
case 'TOGGLE_CART':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        cartOpen: !state.cartOpen
    });
```